# Prechat JScripts creating Duplicate contacts in the Snap-In Rollout

Tags: javascript, liveagent

Currently roll-out Snap-Ins Yesterday (used below Prechat  JScripts). Found that they are creating duplicate Contacts everytime customer log a chat.

This is creating huge problem linking the contacts and Chat to the original Contacts.

Did anyone had issues. Any suggestions to improve the Script.

There aren't much predefined functions in Snap-In like the

```
Live Agent   (  liveagent.findOrCreate('Contact').map('Email','Contact E-mail',true,true,true).map('FirstName','First Name',false,false,true).map('LastName','Last Name',false,false,true).map('Phone','Phone Number',false,false,true); )



embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatInfo = [{

              'entityName': 'Contact',

               'showOnCreate': true,

              'linkToEntityName': 'Case',

              'linkToEntityField': 'ContactId',

              'saveToTranscript': 'ContactId',

              'entityFieldMaps': [{

                'isExactMatch': true,

                'fieldName': 'FirstName',

                'doCreate': true,

                'doFind': true,

                'label': 'First Name'

              },



              {

                  'isExactMatch': true,

                  'fieldName': 'PK__c',

                  'doCreate': true,

                  'doFind': true,

                  'label': 'PK'

                },

                {

                    'isExactMatch': true,

                    'fieldName': 'DefaultB2BUnit__c',

                    'doCreate': true,

                    'doFind': true,

                    'label': 'DefaultB2BUnit'

                  },



              {

                'isExactMatch': true,

                'fieldName': 'LastName',

                'doCreate': true,

                'doFind': true,

                'label': 'Last Name'

              }, {

                'isExactMatch': true,

                'fieldName': 'Email',

                'doCreate': true,

                'doFind': true,

                'label': 'Contact E-mail'

              }]

            }, {

              'entityName': 'Case',

              'showOnCreate': true,

              'saveToTranscript': 'CaseId',

              'entityFieldMaps': [{

                'isExactMatch': false,

                'fieldName': 'Subject',

                'doCreate': true,

                'doFind': false,

                'label': 'Case Subject'

              }, {

                'isExactMatch': false,

                'fieldName': 'Status',

                'doCreate': true,

                'doFind': false,

                'label': 'Status'

              }, {

                'isExactMatch': false,

                'fieldName': 'Origin',

                'doCreate': true,

                'doFind': false,

                'label': 'Origin'

              }]

            }];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go to setup, then search for global actions you can find a global action with a name that contains Snapin and delete it. This should get rid of the duplicate problem.